# mysql group by in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table this structure :

```
id || groupid || name

1  || 23      || John
2  || 25      || Maria
3  || 23      || William
```

Now how can I group this by group id to get this result :

```
23 - John,William
25 - Maria
```

Comment: Just a normal way Select groupid,name from databse GROPU BY groupid but display just one name from each

Comment: See [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT groupid, GROUP_CONCAT(name separator ',') as groupname FROM table GROUP BY groupid;
```

Comment: The separator is not the one requested by the asker

Comment: im not sure if "styling" string inside the query is good, anyway it's right

Comment: +1, but note that the default separator is a comma. So `GROUP_CONCAT(name)` is acceptable.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(name separator ',') as groupname
$row['groupname'];

Answer (score 2):

SQLFIDDLE Solution:

SQLFIDDLE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db32d/15